# What does the regex '/^$/d' mean?

Tags: regex, unix

I was trying to remove blank lines in a file using bash script. Now when i was searching in the INTERNET, i came across two variations of it. In one, we can directly modify the source file and in the other we can store the out put in another file . Here are the code snippets :

```
sed -i '/^$/d' fileName.txt

sed '/^$/d' fileName.txt > newFileName.txt
```

What i could not understand is how the regex  '/^$/d' can be interpreted as blank lines. I am afraid i am not good in regex . Can some one explain me this one ?

Also is there some other way to do it ?

Comment: `/^$/d` is not a regex.  It is a `sed` command containing the regular expression `^$`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for helping me out here. This one was bugging me for a long time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/^$/d


/ - start of regex
^ - start of line
$ - end of line
/ - end of regex
d - delete lines which match
```

So basically find any line which is empty (start and ending points are the same, e.g. no chars), and delete them.

Comment: Great answer . Cleared  a lot of doubts that i had. Thanks a lot . up voted and will accept  .

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the regex explanation:

```
/^$/d
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches end of the line. so `^$` will match empty lines.

You're also using `d` flag with `sed`. This will remove the matched lines.

and `-i` switch in `sed -i '/^$/d' fileName.txt` makes `sed` remove the lines in-place. If you omit that, it will output the result to standard-output.

Comment: ahh , thanks a lot for explaining the 2nd variation. Upvoted .

Answer (score 1):

`/^$/d` is a `sed` command that removes empty lines. It's actually two things stuck together: a regular expression `/^$/` and a `sed` instruction `d`.

The `/^$/` component is a regular expression that matches the empty string. More specifically, it looks for the beginning of a line (`^`) followed directly by the end of a line (`$`), which is to say an empty line. If there's anything in the line -- whitespace or otherwise -- that pattern won't match since the end of the line won't directly follow the beginning of the line.

The `d` component is a `sed` instruction that means "delete". In this usage, the `d` applies to any line that matches the given regular expression (`/^$/`), so it will delete any empty line.

Because `sed` is running in autoprint mode (without the `-n` switch), it will print all lines that aren't deleted -- so, in this case don't match `/$^/` -- so that command ends up being a filter that removes all empty lines from the input.

Answer (score 1):

`/^$/`: select lines that are empty (`^` matches the start of line, `$` matches the end of line, and so this matches lines that start and immediately end with no intervening content).
`d`: delete matched line.

Answer (score 0):

```
^ - start of a line
$ - end of line
```

so

```
/^$/
```

it matches lines with line beginning followed immediately by end of line. which means, empty lines.

the sed command  with `d` means delete matched lines, that is, remove empty lines.

so basically:

```
sed '/regex/d(elete)'  --this is not a real command line, just for explanation.
```

Answer (score 0):

`^$` represents an empty line because `^` is a zero-width anchor meaning the *start* of the line and `$` is a zero-width anchor meaning the *end* of the line.  Thus `^$` must be zero width (i.e. have no characters at all) to match.  There also cannot be any characters before `^` on the line or after `$` on the line.